# GWTEventService client failed to create listener

Tags: gwt, push, event-listener

I am trying to run the hellogwteventservice shipped with the GWTEventService 2.1.0 and GWT 2.6. I imported the code into the eclipse so that I can run through Eclipse GWT plugin.

However on the Client module when following line called the exception is thrown and I get error stating failed initialized GWTServiceEvent.

```java
theRemoteEventService.addListener(ServerGeneratedMessageEvent.SERVER_MESSAGE_DOMAIN,
    new RemoteEventListener() {

        public void apply(Event anEvent) {
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the latest release of GWT 2.5 ?
In any case the latest release of GWTEventService is 2.1.0 as you mentioned. However this uses an older gwt-servlet-2.1 that is incompatable with the one gwt uses gwt-servlet-2.5. So you have 2 options:

1) Go back to GWT 2.1 (not recommened)

2) Build the latest version of GWTEventService as they have included GWT 2.5 support in the latest sources.

Note: adding the error thrown by your IDE might help to further specify the problem

Comment: can you describe how to build the projeckt ?